# Simple Bayes network

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian-network, bayes

Given the following Bayes network:

[image: BayesNet]

with

- $p(k=t)=.2$
- $p(o=t)=.1$
- $p(s=t|k=f,o=f)=.0$
- $p(s=t|k=f,o=t)=.2$
- $p(s=t|k=t,o=f)=.5$
- $p(s=t|k=t,o=t)=.95$

how would I calculate $p(s=t|o=t)$ and $p(o=t|s=t)$?

I tried the following way:

$p(s=t|o=t) = \dfrac{p(s=t \land o=t)}{p(o=t)} = \dfrac{p(s=t)p( o=t | s=t)}{p(o=t)}$, which obviously doesn't make sense, since I have to caluclate $ p( o=t | s=t)$ with Bayes rule.

Comment: It is not duplicate of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440902/bayes-network-example

It is the same example but the querstion is different. I simply took the same graph and values, it is a conceptual question anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the graph you know $P(s|k,o)$, so to get $P(s|o)$ you need to sum over all possible values of $k$, it will be then:

$$
P(s=t|o=t) = \sum_{i \in {t,f}} P(s=t|o=t,k=i)
$$

which will be equal to :

$$
P(s=t|o=t) =  P(s=t|o=t,k=f) +  P(s=t|o=t,k=t)
$$
In your case it doesn't sum to one your distribution, I think you should change the values.

Hope it helps